# Surround values in on column with " "

Tags: excel, excel-2010

On column A of Excel 2010 I have values separated by commas:

```
V1, V2, V3, V4
```

On column B I need to display the same values but surrounded by "":

```
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it by formula you would use this:

```
="""" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",""", """) & """"
```

[image]